# Noun-adjective agreement

Tags: nouns, adjectives, agreement

What is correct here?

1. it could pay your mortgage and car payments
2. it could pay your mortgage and car payment

The monthly payments are separate and distinct so #1 sounds right, but in #2, mortgage and car modify payment, a single payment—a single mortgage payment, and a single car payment. Instead of saying 'your mortgage payment and car payment' the sentence just leaves out one 'payment'.

If 'or' was used, then payment, singular, would be correct:

3. it could pay your mortgage or car payment

Comment: There's nothing special about "payment". *Mortgage* and *car* modify payment(s). Use different modifiers and noun (and verb): "It could rot your ripe and [your] unripe apple" (one ripe and one unripe apple) or "It could rot your ripe and unripe apples" (multiple ripe and unripe apples.)